# Trying to pull data from Vue components in single file components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is my first time experimenting with Vue.js so it's altogether possible I'm missing something very obvious.

Basically, I have a component that calculates the number of boxes needed for a certain quantity of a printed piece (I work in the print industry).

If needed, I have a button to create an additional component if the printed piece has multiple parts.

I'd like to have a reactive way to update the total number of boxes needed for all parts, but I just can't seem to get there.

Here's a link to my Gitlab repo with the code: https://gitlab.com/dsross/printutils

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm also using Browserify to write the build.js and build.css files referenced in index.html.

Here are my files, in case no one wants to look at the repo:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <calculator v-for="(part, index) in parts" :key="index"></calculator>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="card shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button type="button" class="btn" @click="addPart()">Add Part</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn" @click="totalBoxes">Total Boxes</button>
          <span>Box Total (all parts): </span><span id="grandtotal"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  // import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'
  import Calculator from './components/Calculator.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      Calculator
    },
    methods: {
      addPart: function () {
        console.log("Adding part");
        this.parts.push(Calculator);
      },
      totalBoxes: function () {
        console.log("totalBoxes called");
        let totalBoxes = 0;
        let partTotals = document.querySelectorAll("#partBoxTotal");
        for (var i = 0; i < partTotals.length; i++) {
          totalBoxes += parseInt(partTotals[i].innerHTML);
        }
        this.totalBoxCount = totalBoxes;
        document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerHTML = totalBoxes;
      }
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        parts: [Calculator],
        totalBoxCount: 0
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

**Calculator.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="card shadow-sm" id="boxCalculator">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Paper:
                        <select class="custom-select" v-model="paperWeight">
                            <option v-for="(mweight, paper) in mweights" :key="mweight" v-bind:value="paper">{{paper}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <p>Final Width:
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="finalWidth" id="finalWidth" value="">
                    </p>
                    <p>Final Height:
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="finalHeight" id="finalHeight" value="">
                    </p>
                    <p>Sheets Per Unit:
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="numberOfSheets" id="numberOfSheets" name="numberOfSheets"
                            value="">
                    </p>
                    <p>Quantity:
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="quantity" id="quantity" name='quantity'>
                    </p>
                    <p>Stitched:
                        <input type="checkbox" v-model="stitched" name="stitched" id="stitched" value="">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id='results'>
                        <p id="partWeightTotal">Part Total Weight: {{ totalWeight }}</p>
                        <p><span>Part Box Total: </span><span id="partBoxTotal">{{ boxQuantity }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {
        mWeights,
        stitchedMultiplier,
        maxArea
    } from "../constants.js"

    module.exports = {
        data: function () {
            return {
                paperWeight: this.selected,
                paperType: "",
                finalWidth: "",
                finalHeight: "",
                numberOfSheets: "",
                quantity: "",
                stitched: "",
                boxes: "",
                mweights: mWeights
            }
        },
        computed: {
            squareInches: function () {
                return this.finalHeight * this.finalWidth;
            },
            squareInchWeight: function () {
                let mWeight = mWeights[`${this.paperWeight}`];
                return (mWeight / 1000) / maxArea;
            },
            totalWeight: function () {
                return ((this.squareInches * this.squareInchWeight) * this.numberOfSheets) * this.quantity;
            },
            boxQuantity: function () {
                let boxes = this.totalWeight / 35;
                if (this.stitched) {
                    this.boxes = Math.ceil(boxes * stitchedMultiplier);
                    // this.$root.$emit('box-change', this.boxes);
                    return this.boxes
                } else {
                    this.boxes = Math.ceil(boxes);
                    // this.$root.$emit('box-change', this.boxes);
                    return Math.ceil(this.boxes);
                };
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>boxcalculator2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../favicon.png">
  <title>Box Calculator</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="dist/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/build.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col'>
        <div id="app"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @tony19 So, basically, you're saying it's better to pass the data via the props from the parent so that it originates in the parent and is thus available there?

Comment: Not exactly. On review, the way I passed `parts` to `Calculator` wasn't exactly ideal in your app (even though it behaved as expected). See my revised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like the `App`'s total box count to be updated automatically whenever the individual `Calculator`s determine their box counts. One way to do this is to [emit an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event) from `Calculator` when its box count changes, which could be monitored with a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

There are a couple issues we'll address below:

1. It doesn't make sense (and is inefficient) to store `Calculator` -- a single-file-component definition -- in `this.parts[]`. Instead, it could store meaningful data points, such as `Calculator`'s output.
2. Instead of DOM manipulation (i.e., querying the DOM for an element to get/set its value), opt for modeling the data in Vue, and using [interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text) in the template. This lets Vue automatically display the updated value in the target element. It also obviates the element ID assignments (assuming they were used exclusively for DOM manipulation), simplifying the template for improved readability.

#### Storing Calculator output

In `App`, we must use `this.parts[]` to track the result of each `part`'s calculation (which we'll capture below). We'll define each array element (i.e., a "part") to be:

```
{
  boxes: 0 // box count for this part
}
```

This definition allows a `computed` property (which we'll define later), based on `.boxes`, to be reactive.

So, in `addPart()` and the `data` option:

```
// App.vue
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    addPart() {
      this.parts.push({ boxes: 0 });
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      parts: [{ boxes: 0 }]
    }
  }
}
```

#### Notifying `App` of `Calculator` output

Typically, parents pass [data to children via `props`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props), and children communicate [data to parents with events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events). Alternatives include using a state management library, such as [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), but for the sake of simplicity, we'll use events here.

In `Calculator`, we want to notify the parent (`App`) of changes to the `boxes` value, so we'll add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) that [emits an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event) (e.g., called `boxes-changed`) whenever `boxes` changes:

```
// Calculator.vue
export default {
  //...
  watch: {
    boxes(value) {
      this.$emit('boxes-changed', value);
    }
  }
}
```

In `App`, we'll [listen to the `boxes-changed` event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events), and copy the event detail's value to the current `part`'s `boxes` variable, where `part` is the current array element of `parts[]` being iterated.

```
// App.vue
<calculator v-for="(part, index) in parts" @boxes-changed="part.boxes = $event" :key="index"></calculator>
```

*Breakdown of `@boxes-changed="part.boxes = $event"`:*

- `@boxes-changed="..."`    - listen to `boxes-changed` event emitted from `<calculator>`
- `part.boxes = $event`     - set `part.boxes` to value of event detail

#### Making `totalBoxCount` reactive

With the changes above, we have the tools needed to make `App`'s `totalBoxCount` reactive:

1. Change `totalBoxCount` into a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) that sums up the `.boxes` fields of `this.parts[]`. This property will be computed automatically whenever array elements of `this.parts[]` changes.

   ```
    // App.vue
    export default {
      computed: {
        totalBoxCount() {
          // Note: Alternatively, use a simple for-loop to sum .boxes
          return this.parts
                  .filter(p => p.boxes && !Number.isNaN(p.boxes) // get only parts that have a positive `.boxes` value
                  .map(p => p.boxes)          // map object array into an integer array of `.boxes` values
                  .reduce((p,c) => p + c, 0); // sum all array elements
        },
      },
      data() {
        return {
          parts: [],
          // totalBoxCount: 0   // CHANGED INTO COMPTUED PROP ABOVE
        }
      }
    }
   ```
2. In `App`'s template, use [string interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text) to display `totalBoxCount`:

   ```
   <!-- 
   <span>Box Total (all parts): </span><span id="grandtotal"></span>
   --> <!-- DON'T DO THIS -->
   <span>Box Total (all parts): {{totalBoxCount}}</span>
   ```
3. We might as well remove the *Total Boxes* button (previously used to manually trigger a calculation) from the template:

   ```
   <!--
   <button type="button" class="btn" @click="totalBoxes">Total Boxes</button>
   --> <!-- DELETE -->
   ```

and its associated `click`-handler:

```
    // App.vue
    export default {
      methods: {
        // totalBoxes: function() { /* .. */ } // DELETE THIS
      }
    }
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/2ozo4vplzr)

Comment: I should've removed `totalBoxCount` from my code before asking the question. That property isn't updated when the function is called for some reason. I also tried moving the entire function into `computed` to make it reactive, but that failed as well.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I've digested your fix and understand it. Most appreciated.

Comment: @DanRoss No problem :)